# HP ProLiant DL380 G7 iLO error

Tags: windows-event-log, hp-proliant, ilo

I have a HP ProLiant DL380 G7 server which sent me an email that's got me worried.

```
The system has detected the following event:

SNMP Trap:      9006

Date time:      03/19/2011  11:47:46 PM
Computer:       DC1.domain.local
Source:         Server Agents
Type:           Error
Category:       (4)

Description:
A 'Remote Insight Board Interface Error' trap signifies that the Compaq Remote Insight Board has detected a controller interface error.

Details:
None
```

I looked at my event log and I have a corresponding log in the Event Viewer. I also looked back a bit further and found the following 2 events have happened 3 or 4 times since the beginning of the year.

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        hpqilo3
Date:          19/03/2011 07:06:00
Event ID:      78
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      DC1.domain.local
Description:
The ProLiant Monitor Service is unable to communicate with HP ProLiant iLO 3 Management Controller.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="hpqilo3" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="16642">78</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-03-19T07:06:00.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>7147</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>DC1.domain.local</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
  </EventData>
</Event>



Log Name:      System
Source:        hpqilo3
Date:          19/03/2011 07:06:20
Event ID:      79
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      DC1.domain.local
Description:
The ProLiant Monitor Service is now able to communicate with HP ProLiant iLO 3 Management Controller. 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="hpqilo3" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="16642">79</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-03-19T07:06:20.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>7148</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>DC1.domain.local</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

---

First of all, I notice there is a firmware update available. Do you think this will help me out or is the iLO board (which is on the motherboard right?) or motherboard faulty?

Comment: I have found that HP tends to be pretty bad about publishing problems with iLO, but if you call and give them the error code they will tell you all about it and how to fix it. Definitely try updating the firmware first though.

Comment: http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=4091412&prodNameId=4091432&swEnvOID=4064&swLang=13&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-3380ae888f86436aac54c149eb

Comment: From the link above: "Added firmware to the CD for the following supported options: Integrated Lights Out 3 (iLO 3)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may help you but this is a simple bug probably due to the still-pretty-new iLO v3 code, basically update - hope if fixes it - if not ignore and/or report to HP.

Answer (score 2):

Chopper answered as I was typing but yes update, see if it fixes, if not call HP